# Meus labels/button da minha biblioteca Tkinter não estão aparecendo

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

estou estudando a biblioteca tkinter a pouco tempo,eu comecei a criar esse código, quando eu crio a primeira função "iniciar" o código até abre a janela, mas os labels e button q eu declaro nela, não aparecem .-. alguém pode me mostrar alguma maneira de criar esse programa, ou mostrando oq estou errando ou de alguma outra maneira?

```
from tkinter import *

def iniciar():

    janela2 = Tk()
    janela2.title("Janela de usuário")

    jlabel = Label(janela2, text="Não está aparecendo")
    janela2.geometry('300x300')

    janela = Tk()

    janela.title("Janela Principal")

    l1 = Label(janela, text="Login: ")
    l2 = Label(janela, text="Senha: ")
    b1 = Button(janela, text="CONFIRMAR", command=iniciar)

    b1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    l2.grid(row=1, column=0)

    ed1 = Entry(janela, )
    ed2 = Entry(janela, )
    ed1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    ed2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    janela.geometry("250x100+500+250")
    janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está faltando utilizar o `pack()` para que os os objetos apareçam.

Por exemplo:

```
jlabel = Label(janela2, text="Não está aparecendo")
jlabel.pack()
```

Além disso, você pode escolher a posição, passando ela como parâmentro, no modelo:

```
jlabel = Label(janela2, text="Não está aparecendo")
jlabel.pack(side=LEFT) # pode substituir por RIGHT, TOP e BOTTOM
```